# Is it possible to see Hot Coco and Eggipus Rex leaderboards?

Tags: crash-bandicoot-n-sane-trilogy, crash-bandicoot-warped

In *Crash Bandicoot: Warped* there are 2 secret levels:

- **Level 31, Hot Coco** (reached via Level 14: Road Crash)
- **Level 32, Eggipus Rex** (reached via Level 11: Dino Might)

but their buttons do not appear in the Warp Zone, so how can I see their leaderboards and the thresholds I have to beat for each relic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it's possible. I have yet to find a way to view these, and it appears that others ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/crashbandicoot/comments/6lat6s/is_there_any_way_to_open_the_leaderboards_for_hot/), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/crashbandicoot/comments/6kr22v/how_to_see_hot_coco_and_eggipus_rex_leaderboards/)) have yet to find this information as well, such as in [this thread](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/50102-hot-coco-and-eggipus-rex/):

> No, it's not possible. Write it down on a piece of paper or try to remember it. You can only access Eggipus Rex from the gem path in Dino Might when you're near the second pterodactyl, and you can only access Hot Coco by hitting the alien sign in Road Crash. You can't see any progress-so-far anywhere.

Comment: I feared that, this thing needs to be patched